# how to remove tokens that contains number followed by character using regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex

As the question says, how do I replace a token like `'23abc'` with `''` using regular expression in python. It shouldn't affect for characters tokens like 'hello','jimmy','trip','travel' etc.

my code:

```
import re
str="23abcd"
print re.sub(r"[0-9a-z]","",str)
```

But the code doesn't work if str like 'hello' are passed. It still replaces with `''`. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this pattern:

`re.sub(r"[0-9]+[a-z]+","",str)`

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern="23abcd"
>>> _str = "a mlmsm 23abcd smo jimmy"
>>> re.sub(pattern, "", _str)
'a mlmsm  smo jimmy'
```